# When to apply single responsibility principle?

Tags: typescript, oop

I was working on a project that has a class for Teams. But, I don't know if I should simplify these class's attributes, specifically teamSchema & teamClients, and extract it into another object.

```
class Team {
    teamNumber: number
    clientsSchema: Array<String>
    teamClients: Array<Client>
}
```

Should I extract and turn it into this?

```
class Team {
    teamNumber: number
    teamClients: TeamClients
}

class TeamClients {
    teamClients: Array<Client>
    clientsSchema: Array<String>
}
```

background: This is for a red vs blue team cyber security competition where each team has a team # and clients and each team have the same number of clients and same schema for their clients. The schema is just the IPs of competitors boxes (ex. 10.1.1.x where x is the team #) they need to protect.

full class:

```
class Team {
    teamNumber: number
    teamSchema: Array<String>
    teamClients: Array<Client>

    constructor(teamNumber, teamSchema, teamClients) {
        this.teamNumber = teamNumber
        this.teamSchema = teamSchema
        this.teamClients = teamClients
    }

    // Gets all clients, if client couldn't be found it is pushed as null to the returned array
    getTeamClients(allClients) {
        var teamClients = []
        for(const box of this.teamSchema) {
            const ip = convertXtoNum(box, this.teamNumber)
            const client = getClientByIP(ip)
            teamClients.push(client)
        }
        return teamClients
    }

    hasAllSchemaClients() {
        for(const client of this.teamClients) {
            if(client == null) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    getLowestCheckTime() {
        const currentTime = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000)
        var lowestCheckTime = currentTime
        for(const client of this.teamClients) {
            if(client.lastCheckTime < lowestCheckTime) {
                lowestCheckTime = client.lastCheckTime
            }
        }
        return lowestCheckTime
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion,

the `getTeamClients(allClients)` should be made private and make a constructor that uses it

the `hasAllSchemaClients()` should be moved into a new class like `TeamClients` to separate and help future readability

`getLowestCheckTime()` should be made a private function of the `Team` class as it's purpose is not a behavior of `TeamClients`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).